# File Permissions Reverting to write-only for Wordpress site

Tags: wordpress, posix

I've got a Wordpress site that's won't allow users to edit any Pages.  Editing Settings works fine but whenever I attempt to edit any of the user-created pages, it shows the following warnings and I am unable to save any changes.

```
Warning: file_get_contents(/<base filepath>/wp-content/themes/Avada/404.php): failed to open stream: Permission denied in <base filepath>/wp-includes/class-wp-theme.php on line 1147

Warning: file_get_contents(/<base filepath>/wp-content/themes/Avada/archive.php): failed to open stream: Permission denied in <base filepath>wp-includes/class-wp-theme.php on line 1147
```

For some reason, the theme's `404.php` and `archive.php` only have  write access for the owner: `--w-------`.  The other files in that directory have have less restricted permissions: `-rw----r--`.

My first stab at fixing this was to run `chmod 604` on the files.

After I did that, I attempted to edit the pages.  The errors weren't rendering but when I attempted to preview or save changes, it failed.  When I re-inspect the files, they've reverted to being write only for the owner.

Can anyone tell me how to fix this permissions issue permanently?  I'm curious what else might be responsible for reverting the permissions I set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To rule out ant theme/plugin conflict, try:

- Deactivating ALL (yes all) plugins temporarily to see if this resolves the problem (plugin functions can interfere). If this works, re-activate them individually (one-by-one) to find the problematic plugin(s).
- Switching to the unedited default Theme for a moment using the WP dashboard to rule out any theme-specific issue (theme functions can interfere like plugins).
- If you can install plugins, try [Health Check](https://wordpress.org/plugins/health-check/). On the troubleshooting tab, you can click the button to disable all plugins and change the theme for you, while you’re still logged in, without affecting normal visitors to your site.

Also try to check your user permissions with [Capability Manager Enhanced](https://wordpress.org/plugins/capability-manager-enhanced/).
Then write the results.

Comment: I installed the Health Check plugin and am still seeing the behavior.  Updates continue to fail and more importantly, the permissions continue to revert to `--w-------` after I run `chmod` and update a post.  (It works the first time but fails after a logout/login.)

Comment: I installed  Capability Manager Enhanced and it looks like the main users all have edit permissions for Posts.

Comment: I also replaced the Gutenberg plugin with the Classic editor after researching the "Update Failed" issue I was seeing.  It fixed it temporarily but after logging out/in it reappeared.

Comment: @BenDowney have you tried to deactivate all plugins and then edit the pages? Or switch theme then edit the pages? Need to find where the interference.

Comment: I did both those things via the Health Check plugin.  I suppose I give it a try w/o in case Health Check isn't working as expected.

Comment: @BenDowney Contact to the hosting support. Let them look at the log files at the time of changing permissions to the files. From where the file permissions changing come from.
There is an option that the virus on the site. Need to check that.

Comment: I inspected the contents of the `404.php` and `archive.php` and contained malicious code.  I replaced them with the files from the original template and now the site works as expected. Thanks for your help on this!